# Traco DC DC Can I connect -Vin and -Vout

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I'm using Tracopower TEL 5-1211.
Can I connect both -Vin and -Vout to gnd of my design?

Thanks

Comment: Your question makes no sense either electrically or grammatically.

Comment: Sorry, orthographic corrector did wrong. I updated the post.

Comment: Funny how just that one tiny mistake changed the entire question! That is much easier to understand now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an isolated converter so you can. You could even connect +Vout to -Vin...or +Vout to +Vin if you wanted to. It would remove the isolation of the converter so it's a waste. You should just use a cheaper non-isolated converter instead.

Comment: "It's an isolated converter so you can.".  While **most-often** true, it's good practice to check the datasheet (or prototype it), because there are some odd-ducks that cannot be connected this way.

Comment: "it's a waste"... not necessarily true. There could be reasons to use an isolated converter other than its isolation. Using multiple of the same part instead of several different parts is the most straightforward, but also there could be advantages of the isolated topology other than just the isolation, or you may want to be able to control whether it's isolated or not via a switch or relay.